# How to send request using a specific IP address to an website with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to execute a script to access an website binding to a specific IP address.  I found something in C# to do that using BindIpEndPointDelegate class.

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://google.com/");
req.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = BindTo;
 using (req.GetResponse());

 static IPEndPoint BindTo(ServicePoint servicepoint, IPEndPoint remoteendpoint, int retrycount)
{
IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Any; //This is where you specify the network adapter's address
int port = 0; //This in most cases should stay 0. This when 0 will bind to any port     available.
return new IPEndPoint(ip, port);
 }
```

I don't know how to pass that class to powershell.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: What kind of access are you talking about? A vanilla GET request? POST? Or something completely different?

Comment: Actually, I just need to do an HttpWebRequest to check the website status. My problem is that website is behind a load balance which has different instances of that website with different ip addresses. I'd like to send a request to all of them. That's why I need BindIPEndPointDelegate to specify each ip address and port.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try (not tested), this is the PowerShell equivalent of the C# code:

```
function Bind-IPEndPointCallback([System.Net.IPAddress]$ip,$port)
{
        New-Object -TypeName System.Net.IPEndPoint $ip, $port
}

$request = [System.Net.HttpWebRequest]::Create("http://somewhere.com")
$request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate={ (Bind-IPEndPointCallback -ip 10.10.10.10 -port 80 ) }
$request.GetResponse()
```